# Is the standard part function another devil's staircase?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

The devil's staircase or [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is an awesome function that increases value but has derivative zero everywhere (or "almost", whatever that means).

I was incredibly amazed when I found out that the standard part function also seems to have derivative zero, no matter how you take it (I'll just show forwards):

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{d(\text{st}\ x)}{dx}=
\text{st}\frac{\text{st}(x+dx)-\text{st}(x)}{dx}=
\text{st}\frac{\cancel{\text{st}(x)}+\text{st}(dx)\cancel{-\text{st}(x)}}{dx}=
\text{st}\frac{0}{dx}=0
$$

Which is odd, since the standard part function looks exactly like the identity function, $y=x$, when plotted, well, with a normal real scale. When magnified with the infinitesimal microscope, one would see a straight horizontal line, as all nonstandard numbers would be "rounded" to the nearest real.

[image: Standard part function. $\delta$ is an infinitesimal]

This reminds me of the floor function, but somehow this one doesn't seem to have discontinuities (it really doesn't, for any infinitesimal $\Delta x$, there's always an infinitesimal $\Delta(\text{st}\ x)=0$).

I'm confused, what's wrong here? Does the standard part function really have derivative zero everywhere?

Comment: "Almost everywhere" means that the set of exceptions has measure $0$. And there are exceptions: The Cantor function is not differentiable at all points, for example. A set has measure $0$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$, it can be covered with (non-degenerate) intervals, the sums of whose lengths is at most $\epsilon$. For example, the Cantor set has measure $0$.

Comment: @Andres, yeah... ...I read that on Wikipedia but am not sure about what that means. I think a non-degenerate interval is something that isn't like $[a;a]=\{a\}$. But then I don't understand how an interval can have a non-integer length: given that the sum of the lengths is smaller than $\epsilon$ which may be smaller than $1$.

Comment: $(3.1,3.2)$ has length $0.1$, and $(0.76,0.93]$ has length $0.17$.

Answer (score 3):

Formally this calculation does give "slope" zero at every point but it is important to realize that the usual formula for the slope should only be applied to natural extensions of real functions or more generally to [internal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set) functions.  The standard part function ("shadow") is not internal and therefore this definition is meaningless for it.

To elaborate, note that we are generally interested in real functions, i.e. functions of a real argument taking real values. In the infinitesimal approach, we typically seek to understand a real function $f$ via its natural extension ${}^\ast\! f$ which is now a function from hyperreals to hyperreals. In other words, what interests us is not the extension ${}^\ast\mathbb{R}$ per se.  Rather, we are interested in the *pair* $\mathbb{R}\subset{}^\ast\mathbb{R}$. We exploit the relationship between the reals and the hyperreals to study the properties of real functions. Thus, continuity and differentiability of $f$ can be defined via $^\ast\!f$ exploiting infinitesimals. The standard part function does not arise as the natural extension of any real function. There is a larger class of functions than those given by natural extensions. These are the *internal* functions. For these it still makes sense to explore the usual notions using infinitesimals. But the standard part function is not even internal. That's why it seems to behave paradoxically when it comes to the usual notions like continuity and differentiability.

What is unusual here is that we view "st" as a kind of "liaison officer" between $\mathbb{R}$ and $^\ast\mathbb{R}$ and are not really interested in its properties as a function in its own right. The fact that we are working with a *pair* of continua rather than a single continuum as in the traditional approach is the revolutionary feature of NSA. The special status of the standard part is even more pronounced in Edward Nelson's framework *Internal Set Theory*, where "st" is *not even a function* (it does exist as a unary predicate).

Comment: So in this function the slope isn't given by the derivative? Or is the derivative defined in another way? Which one is ill-defined in this case?

Comment: @JMCF125 My understanding of this topic is limited, but I believe the problem is that the standard part function, unlike your usual function, was not extended to the hyperreals from the reals in the natural way.  To ellaborate: usually, you calculate the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by "extending" it to a function on the hyperreals.  Since the standard part function was not extended from a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it makes little sense to talk about its derivative.

Comment: @Goos, +1, I see, but then how can you know the slope?

Comment: @JMCF125, what I tried to explain in my answer is that we are not interested in the notion of slope for the standard part function. In other words, this notion is arguably meaningless for non-internal functions. Compare this to looking for Lebesgue measure of a non-measurable set.

Comment: I see. +1, but I'm still thinking, and will not mark this answer as accepted just yet.